# How can I represent relationships between instances of the same class in a concurrent system

Tags: sockets, uml, class-diagram

I made a concurrent system which has a critical section which involves read and write access to a TXT file.

First, an Auctioneer class creates a TXT file and writes the number 50 to it. The Auctioneer then allows the next node, one of three instances of the Bidder class, to open the file and change the current bid. The bidder class then allows the next node, another bidder to bid, then another bidder, and then that bidder allows the Auctioneer to look at the file.
I allowed the nodes to take turns using server sockets. Each node waits for access using the [ServerSocket.accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method, and allows the next node to enter its critical section by creating a [Socket object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) with the socket that ne next nde is listening on.

Each of these nodes run independantly in seperate java environments and only communicate with server sockets.

Each node of the ring relies on the previous node because in order for that node to access the resource, the previous node needs to pass the current node the token. I'm unsure on how I would represent that kind of relationship in a UML compliant way.

It is of my understanding that class diagrams should not include several instances of the same class such as the example below with 3 bidders.

[image: one possible class diagram]

Is this the correct way to represent the relationship which I have described? If not, which way would be better/UML compliant?

Comment: Every Bidder has an association with one (or more?) other Bidders, which is a reflexive loop at the class level.

Comment: If you would use an object diagram ISO the class diagram you would be done as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class diagrams, as the name suggest represent classes of objects and not individual objects, i.e. instances of  these classes. Moreover, a class diagram is structural: it does not tell how objects interact or wait one for another, but how classes relate.

In tour case the class diagram would therefore represent one bidder class. To represent a concrete example with instances and how they relate, you could consider an object diagram. There you could very well represent different instances of the same class.

However, if you’re interested in the interactions between classes (e.g. the tokens they exchange), you’d better consider an interaction diagram such as the sequence diagram.